# Equivalence Class of the relation {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3)}

Tags: relations

The above relation is equivalent for the set {0,1,2,3}. How would you find the equivalence class for this relation or any general relational set of pairs of integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that each element of $\,\{0, 1,2,3\}\,$ belongs to exactly one singleton subset of the given relation and, thus, this equiv. relation is equivalent (isomorphic, if you will) with the equality relation.

Comment: So for the element 0, the equivalent class would be the subset {(0,0)}?

Comment: @user1766888: No, the equivalence classes are subsets of the underlying set $\{0,1,2,3\}$, not of the relation. The equivalence class of $0$ is $\{0\}$, since $0$ is the only thing related to $0$ by that relation.

Comment: Brian is correct and I miswrote (or, if you will, wrote something that can easily be misinterpreted): every element of the given set is related only to itself and thus only the singleton of the *given set* (not of the relation!) containing it is its equiv. class.

Answer (score 3):

Let the relation be called $R$. Then, $(a,b)\in R$ means that the pair $(a,b)$ is in relation $R$, and this fact is also often denoted simply by $aRb$.
Now this $R$ relation is just the *equality* relation on the base set 
$\{0,1,2,3\}$.

In general, if $R$ is an equivalence relation, an element $x$ belongs to the equivalence class of another element $a$ iff $x$ and $a$ are 'equivalent according to $R$', that is, $aRx$, in other words, $(a,x)\in R$.